# Android - Getting context from a Broadcast receiver onReceive() to send to

Tags: android, android-intent, service, broadcastreceiver, android-context

I basically want to make an intent and pass it to a service from my BroadcastReceiver's onReceive().

So far I always used View.getContext(), but here, I'm stuck.
How exactly can I get the context so I can use `public Intent (Context packageContext, Class<?> cls)`?

Answer (score 320, accepted):

```
public abstract void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
```

`onReceive` gives you the context. What more do you want?

Comment: Oh seriously, I didnt see it until I see this.

Comment: This doesn't work. I'm trying to call the broadcast from a service and the context I'm trying to get is a `MyService` object, but the `context` argument is a `ReceiverRestrictedContext` object.

Answer (score 2):

Well the Answer mentioned above is not of any use. You can use the context as long as you are in onReceive. once you code has returned from onReceive, the context is no longer existing.

So your problem statement say you wanted to start the service using this context in your intent creation and then calling startService with this context object. That cannot be done.

Read this what can and cannot be done in BroadcastReceiver context.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: what you said is not true. you can start a service from BroadcastReceivers, but cannot bind to them.

Answer (score 1):

In the BroadcastReceiver the

```
onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
```

method provides context

so

to start activity use

```
context.startActivity(intent);
```

and to start service use

```
context.startService(intent);
```